# improve setState with TextInput or Pickers in React & ReactNative & ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, ecmascript-6

This code is currently working, but I don't know if there is a way to do it better, or at least more reusable.

I am working with reactNative but maybe this is more an ES6 question.

**The State:**

```
    state = {
        editorial: "",
        nivel: "",
        asignatura: "",
        txt: ""
    };
```

I have a TextInput, for the txt and the rest are Pickers.
So, this is how I update all the data from that state:

```
    onChangeInput = txt => this.setState({txt});
    setEditorial = editorial => this.setState({editorial})
    setNivel = nivel => this.setState({nivel})
    setAsignatura = asignatura => this.setState({asignatura})
```

I am trying to do it more reusable at least for the pickers... how can I achive that??

Comment: This all looks fine, if the different parts of the state are being updated separately then you should keep the functions separate as you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

Try using computed property names:

```
changeValue = (name, val) => this.setState({ [name]: val });
```